Firebase authentication using facebook shows warning
I am trying to use Firebase to sign in with Facebook, but in the sign-in pop-up window it is showing a warning message

How can I fix this issue? I only want to get the user's basic info for sign up like email, name, and uid
I created the app, in which I chose Facebook login only and provided a redirect URL as asked in Firebase, the sign-in is working fine but I am able to log in only with the test accounts added.
I used the below code to make a request to Facebook
const provider = new FacebookAuthProvider();
await signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then((result) => {
      // The signed-in user info.
      user = result.user;

      const credential = FacebookAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
      const accessToken = credential.accessToken;
    })


To use certain features, you need to submit the app you created at facebook developer dashboard to review. Once they approve it, you can use it.

@SagarV even for email address, profile picture and name i need to submit app for review?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions#categories
In the official docs it is mentioned "App Review  is required for all permissions except for email and public_profile if your app needs access to data that you do not own or manage" does name and profile picture does not comes under public_profile?
